# Inactive Contact can be found using Advanced Find but is missing in View

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a couple of DEACTIVATED contacts that I can see by using just the Last Name in an Advanced Find Query. But I cannot see them in the Inactive Contacts view. The records open as Inactive. Why am I not seeing these records in the view?

Comment: There may be many reason like Do you have proper rights ,condition of Inactive Contact View or many more..so can you share some more details

Comment: I have checked the filter for the Inactive Contact View, it does not have any condition other than Status equals Inactive. So it is definitely not it. I can see the records using an Advanced Find query so it is not a rights issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any hidden filter conditions, which will be hidden in simple mode. So you may be missing to notice this condition.

[image]